# Maximal finite order of Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a commutative group, and let $g$ be an element of $G$ be an element of maximal finite order, then $|h|\leq |g|$. Prove that in fact if $h$ is finite order in $G$, then $|h|$ divides $|g|$.

This is what I have:

Proof by contradiction
If $|h|$ is finite but doesn't divide $|g|$, then there is a prime integer $p$ such that $|g|=rp^m$, $|h|=sp^n$, with $r$ and $s$ relatively prime to $p$ and $m < n$.

(This is where I do not know where to go.)

Comment: Your conclusion on $r,s,p,m$ is wrong.

Comment: How? Please explain?

Comment: Why would $r$ and $s$ be relatively prime to $m$?

Comment: Sorry there was an error in the question. I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the $|h|$ doesn't divide $|g|$, then $|h|$ contains a prime factor with multiplicity higher than in $|g|$.  This tells us that $gh$ has order greater than that of $g$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: That's it!?!?!?!? That was simple. Is this a rigourous proof?

Comment: I mean, you might want to flesh out the details, but I'm pretty sure the reasoning is sound.

Comment: Since the statement in question is in general false for non-commutative groups, a correct argument needs to use the commutativity.  Where did you do so in your answer?

Comment: Commutativity tells us that $|gh| = \hbox{lcm}(|g|,|h|)$?